# Convert SQL into Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT
  m1.id
FROM
  messages m1
WHERE
  m1.to_id = 1 AND m1.created_at < (
    SELECT 
      m2.created_at
    FROM
      messages m2
    WHERE
      m2.from_id = m1.to_id AND m2.to_id = m1.from_id)
GROUP BY
    m1.id
```

How can i convert into eloquent? I done this until now, but a don't know what to do in the part of where on subquery.

```
Message::where('to_id', 1)
            ->where('created_at', '<', function($q) {
               $q->from('messages');
               $q->select('created_at');
            })
            ->select('id')
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Message::where('to_id', 1)
            ->where('created_at', '<', function($q) {
                $q->from('messages AS m2')
                  ->select('created_at')
                  ->where('m2.from_id ','=', 'messages.to_id ')
                  ->where('m2.to_id','=','messages.from_id');
            })
            ->select('id')
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: The code executes, but it does not find any results. When I run sql on the database it returns normal.

Comment: I think the problem is in the where of the subquery, because I replace them with numbers and returned the results.

Comment: I did this just for test.  ->where('m2.from_id ','=', '1 ')->where('m2.to_id','=','2');

Comment: You have to use `whereColumn()` instead of `where()`.